# Error in installing Opencv on linux

Tags: linux, opencv, cuda

I am trying to install Opencv in linux platform. Basically, I am following http://sysads.co.uk/2014/05/install-opencv-2-4-9-ubuntu-14-04-13-10/.

But whenever I am trying to build samples I am getting the following error-

```
compiling contours.c
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcufft
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnpps
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnppi
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnppc
```

However, I have all these files in /usr/local/cuda-7.5/.
I have CUDA installed properly. the output of `lspci  -v -s  $(lspci | grep VGA | cut -d" " -f 1)`

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GL [Quadro K600] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 094b
    Physical Slot: 2
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    Memory at ee000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at ef000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Please help.

Comment: If what you edited into your question is your solution, please add it as and answer. You will later be able to accept your own answer, and this will get the question off the unanswered queue and make the answer more visible in search.

Comment: Sorry! Done! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this by editing `build_all.sh` which can be found in `/usr/local/share/OpenCV/samples/c` directory. 
New build_all.sh is:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -gt 0 ] ; then
    base=`basename $1 .c`
    echo "compiling $base"
    gcc -ggdb -L /usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64 `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` $base.c -o $base
else
    for i in *.c; do
        echo "compiling $i"
        gcc -ggdb -L /usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64 `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o `basename $i .c` $i `pkg-config --libs opencv`;
    done
    for i in *.cpp; do
        echo "compiling $i"
        g++ -ggdb -L /usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64 `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o `basename $i .cpp` $i `pkg-config --libs opencv`;
    done
fi
```